# ACRA sends empty request

Tags: android, acra

I am using this configuration to send the crashes to my own server.

```
formUri = "http://server/app"+HttpClient.CRASH_URL,
    customReportContent = {ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
    reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON
```

My logcat output

```
    11-23 17:21:15.608  29922-29922/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/user/0/com.parchee.app/files
11-23 17:21:15.826  29922-29922/? E/ACRA﹕ ACRA caught a RuntimeException for com.parchee.app
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parchee.app/com.parchee.app.activity.IntroductionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.parchee.app.activity.IntroductionActivity.onCreate(IntroductionActivity.java:71)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-23 17:21:15.826  29922-29922/? D/ACRA﹕ Building report
11-23 17:21:15.829  29922-29922/? D/ACRA﹕ Using custom Report Fields
11-23 17:21:15.910  29922-29922/? I/ACRA﹕ READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
11-23 17:21:15.926  29922-29922/? D/ACRA﹕ Retrieving logcat output...
11-23 17:21:15.957  29922-29922/? D/ACRA﹕ Writing crash report file 1448279475000.stacktrace.
11-23 17:21:15.976  29922-29922/? D/ACRA﹕ About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
11-23 17:21:15.977  29922-29940/? D/ACRA﹕ Mark all pending reports as approved.
11-23 17:21:15.977  29922-29940/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/user/0/com.parchee.app/files
11-23 17:21:15.979  29922-29940/? D/ACRA﹕ #checkAndSendReports - start
11-23 17:21:15.979  29922-29940/? D/ACRA﹕ Looking for error files in /data/user/0/com.parchee.app/files
11-23 17:21:15.980  29922-29940/? I/ACRA﹕ Sending file 1448279475000-approved.stacktrace
11-23 17:21:15.985  29922-29941/? D/ACRA﹕ Waiting for Toast
11-23 17:21:15.987  29922-29941/? D/ACRA﹕ Finished waiting for Toast
11-23 17:21:15.987  29922-29941/? D/ACRA﹕ Waiting for Worker
11-23 17:21:15.995  29922-29940/? D/ACRA﹕ Connect to http://192.168.1.35:8000/docpad/crashes/
11-23 17:21:16.021  29922-29940/? D/ACRA﹕ Sending request to http://server/docpad/crashes/
11-23 17:21:16.290  29922-29940/? E/ACRA﹕ Failed to send crash report for 1448279475000-approved.stacktrace
    org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending JSON report via Http POST
            at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:250)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:178)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:140)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:76)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Host returned error code 500
            at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:179)
            at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:247)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:178)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:140)
            at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:76)
11-23 17:21:16.290  29922-29940/? D/ACRA﹕ #checkAndSendReports - finish
11-23 17:21:16.387  29922-29941/? D/ACRA﹕ Finished waiting for Worker
11-23 17:21:16.388  29922-29941/? D/ACRA﹕ Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
11-23 17:21:16.388  29922-29941/? D/ACRA﹕ Handing Exception on to default ExceptionHandle
```

**Update**

I have tried sending email as well via acra, which works fine but not via a POST request with a json type data encoding.

**Contents of the received request on the server**
[image: Print out for the received request]

Comment: Your server is returning a 500 error code. Talk to whoever is maintaining your server and ask them what is going on over on the server side.

Comment: Its returning because the request is empty. I can post the server request printout if you say so  ?

Comment: Where's the content of the post?

Comment: Report fields are the content , right ?